# What is the meaning of the "eye symbol" on a corrected proof?

Tags: publications, editors, proofreading

I have submitted my corrections of the proofs to a Wiley journal, in the corrections, I have corrected a typo in one of the equations, the typo was not made by the typesetter but rather by me, in the last version of the accepted paper. After they have sent me a link summarizing the made corrections, while scrolling though the proof, I found the following symbol (see attached image).
[image]

I'm worried that the "eye symbol" means that the paper needs verification from the editor, before making the change, since this symbol was only on the change that I have made on the equation. Is anyone familiar with the symbol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know specifically about Wiley, but the eye symbol is frequently used as a proofreading or copy-editor mark to direct an author to look at a section of the paper and to (re)check that it is correct. For example, see [here](https://arphahub.com/manual) near the text: "all reviews will be marked with ..."